# Excel formula to get the lowest n values from a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some values in a column which are not necesarily sorted. Then I want to find the average of the lowest n values from the column with the values.

[image: column values]

So let's take the example above. Say I need to average `n=3` lowest values from the column above with values ranging from `A1` to `A10`. The result will be the average of 1 (taken from A1), 2 (taken from A6) and 3 (taken from A2). I am thinking of something like `AVERAGE(LOWEST_N(A1:A10, 3))` but I'm not sure it can be as simple as that.

Note: I can't sort the values on that specific column. I also do not wish to manually move the values to another column and sort them there, because I want to do this many multiple times and I need to automate the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array formula, using ctrl, shift and enter to confirm.

```
=AVERAGE(SMALL(A1:A10,ROW(1:3)))
```

Comment: Brilliant! Didn't know about that. By pressing ctrl-shift-enter this actually turns into

```=ArrayFormula(AVERAGE(SMALL(A1:A10,ROW(1:3))))```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `=AVERAGEIF(A1:A10, "<4")`

Comment: Thank you, but it's not what I want. The column could be very big and I do not wish to manually search for a value to compare with (i.e. the 4 in your example). Plus, the values might not be unique